# How to replace all character like (--) in vector data 0 using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I have 3 columns of data in myfile.dat file. They are ordered like below.

```
  234   -642  20.20
  233   -640  20.40
  233.4  --   20.60
  --    -646  20.80
  --    -642  21.00
  234   --    21.20
  342   --    21.40
  ...   ...   .....
```

I want to plot them using matplotlib python but before that I want to replace
-- character by 0 in all columns so that I can understand what time it is becoming zero. At this time I am doing it manually but want to do it programmatically. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for something like this?

```
infile = open('test.dat')
outfile = open('clean.dat', 'w')
for line in infile:
    outfile.write(line.replace('--', '0'))

outfile.close()
infile.close()
```

`clean.dat` now has data with '--' replaced with '0' fore example:

```
  234   -642  20.20
  233   -640  20.40
  233.4  0   20.60
  0    -646  20.80
  0    -642  21.00
  234   0    21.20
  342   0    21.40
```

**Edit:**
To open and overwrite some file you can do something like this:

```
FILE = 'test.dat

f = open(FILE)
infile =  f.read() #infile is one big string with the whole doc

f.close()
outfile = open(FILE, 'w') #this will OVERWIRTE the original!!
outfile.write(infile.replace('--', '0'))

outfile.close()
```

Comment: ,Thanks a lot ,I was thinking something  hard and thus confused. But it is simple and easy. Okay just asking is it possible to save it in the same file so that I can plot it through same file otherwise I have to load it from another file for further processing.

Comment: Yes you can open the file and then write to the same file -- see edit. Be careful though! You can also read the original, replace the content in memory and just work with it without saving over the file. That might be safer and just as easy unless another program needs to read the files.

Comment: Thanks Mark_M. I will go through it. Thanks one and all.

Comment: Okay, because my directory is already full of intermediate files, so I came up with this idea. I have completed with your previous suggestions.

Comment: I just find another problem. Earlier using replace function I have replaced to my desired data. Now in the same vector column I have two undesired data, i.e (--) and PD . In both cases I want to replace by 0. I tried replace('--,PD', '0'))

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` is a good library for reading structured data and plays well with `matplotlib`.
When reading in a file you can specify additional `NaN` values, which are easy to replace with `.fillna(0)`, e.g.:

```
In []:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.dat', delim_whitespace=True, header=None, na_values=['--']).fillna(0)
df
Out[]:
       0      1     2
0  234.0 -642.0  20.2
1  233.0 -640.0  20.4
2  233.4    0.0  20.6
3    0.0 -646.0  20.8
4    0.0 -642.0  21.0
5  234.0    0.0  21.2
6  342.0    0.0  21.4

In []:
df.plot()
Out[]:
```

[image]

Comment: This is one of my step in my python script. This I have extracted from one my complex  input text file. When I extracted particular column and saved to another text file , I have faced previous problem. So my thought was how to remove (-- )missing data by 0 and then plot it. So I want to keep it in the same format. Small doubt whether I can save it in the same file after replacing missing data by 0

Comment: Understood, `pandas` is good for working with structured data (basically excel in python) - you may want to explore, e.g you can write it back out with `pd.write_csv(...)`.

Comment: Okay Thanks . Last but not the least I am adding one more criteria in the same question. Whenever my data become zero I want to give them separate color ,say red so that I can differentiate from other elements.Is it possible to plot like this .

Comment: That is a separate question, I would ask it separately once you have this part resolved.

Comment: Okay right now I have completed my process with Mark_M suggestions .I understood your part also .Previous one was my curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

After you have loaded the data file, replace the `'--'` with `0` in each column:

```
new_column = [0 if cell=='--' else cell for cell in old_column]
```

This statement uses the [conditional operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and a generator expression `[f(x) for x in a_list]`.

Comment: Thanks for response . But I did not get how to define old_column and cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match whatever sequence you want and replace it:

```
import re

file_path = './t'
file_out_path = './tt'

# Open the source file
# it will close it automatically at the end of the `with` block
with open(file_path, 'r+') as source:
  content = source.read()
  # match the sequence you want and replace it
  content = re.sub('--', '00', content)
  # You can do with it as you wish, like writing it back to another file
  with open(file_out_path, 'w') as destination:
    destination.write(content)
```